# Can't change dark theme style for MetroListView in c#

Tags: c#

I use metro ui form and tried to change dark theme style for metro listview. But I don't know why metro list view them is always a light theme when I run

[image]

And when I run it, It's always a light themes style.

Is there any wrong with metro listview

Answer (score 0):

use `this.Refresh()` Method May Be That Can Cause The Theme To **Change** !